# scipy differential evolution setup issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, scipy-optimize

Below is a very stupid example which is basically a dumbing-down of my real world use case

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import time

def optimizer_function(x, cost_name):
    print(cost_name)
    a = df_generator(x)
    return cost_function(a,cost_name)

def df_generator(x):
    return pd.DataFrame({"a":[x**2+3*x+8 for i in range(-int(x),int(x))]})

def cost_function(df, name):
    cost = min(df["a"])
    if name == "distance":
        cost = 2*cost
    return cost


def optimiser(criteria):
    print("start optimization")
    start = time.process_time()
    print(start)
    result = differential_evolution(func=optimizer_function, bounds=[(-100,100)], 
                                    args=(criteria))
    end = time.process_time()
    print(end)
    print(end - start)
    print("end optimization")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    optimiser("distance")
    print("all good")
```

I cannot get it to work though.
I would expect it to give me the value of `x` that minimizes the `cost_function` but instead I get the following error message :

> RuntimeError: The map-like callable must be of the form f(func, iterable), returning a sequence of numbers the same length as 'iterable'

It sounds like I am not setting the problem correctly or that my functions do not return the right type of data for `differential_evolution` to interpret correctly but I have no idea where I should correct.

Any help welcome

here is the stack

```py
  File "H:/projects/decay-optimizer/test_diff_evo.py", line 33, in <module>
    optimiser("distance")
  File "H:/projects/decay-optimizer/test_diff_evo.py", line 25, in optimiser
    args=(criteria))
  File "H:\projects\decay-optimizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentialevolution.py", line 276, in differential_evolution
    ret = solver.solve()
  File "H:\projects\decay-optimizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentialevolution.py", line 688, in solve
    self.population)
  File "H:\projects\decay-optimizer\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentialevolution.py", line 794, in _calculate_population_energies
    raise RuntimeError("The map-like callable must be of the"
RuntimeError: The map-like callable must be of the form f(func, iterable), returning a sequence of numbers the same length as 'iterable'
```

Comment: New the the traceback to see where the error occured

Comment: Try `args=(criteria,)`.  The comma creates a tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`args=(criteria,)`
from @hpaulj answer.